# Initializing a static const char* array with text file data?

Tags: c++

I have a text file containing words
Every word in a single line.
And I have this array in my c++ code:
`static const char *array[]= {"text"};`

How do I initialize the array with all the txt file data ?

I know how to initialize int array with this data using ifstream, but I don't know how to do it with static const char *

Comment: Please be more focused. If you know how to work with integers, please provide the code that you think does that. Also describe what is the complication with strings if the integers work for you.

Comment: You cannot have such an array in your C++ code, you are mistaken. In C++ all arrays have a known, fixed size. You must've misunderstood something about your homework assignment or practice problem. You'll need to figure out what it is, as such this question is not unaswerable based on the information in the question.

Comment: if the data in the file was comma separated and quoted, you could compile the file in: `static const char *array[] = {<newline>#include"file.txt"<newline> };`, but there's no way to have constant array and then read a file into it at runtime.

Comment: If you add the verbatim text of the assignment for us to read we can probably offer you alternatives.

Comment: If you define array like this, `static const char **array`, then you can do it with two passes. One to count the number of words and allocated an array of pointers with new. The second to allocate space for each word and trailing null. Terminate using a single null so you can detect the end of the word list. This is how the main function passes arguments: `char ** argv`